# Как передать значение datepicker?

Tags: jquery, json, get, datepicker

Не могу передать значение инпута datepciker, как это можно реализовать?
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js    datepicker

```
<form id="filter">
                     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                                 <div class="col-md-3">       
         <span>Дата документа</span>
        <div id="dpcontainer" class="ui-widget">

         С <input type="text" id="pDateBeg">  ДО <input type="text" id="pDateEnd">
        </div>
<script>
$('#pDateBeg').datepicker({
    autoClose: true
})
$('#pDateEnd').datepicker({
    autoClose: true
})

</script>
 </div>





  <div class="col-md-7">  

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span>Статус</span>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="p-status" name="pStatus">
                            <option value="3">Все</option>
                            <option value="2">В работе</option>
                            <option value="1">Завершеные</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span>Тип</span>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="p-type" name="pType">
                            <option value="1">Все</option>
                            <option value="2">Важные</option>

                        </select>
</div>
</div>
                   </div>   

                        <input type="hidden" name="pDateEnd" value="<?= $_GET['pDateEnd'] ?>" />
                        <input id="pDateBeg" type="hidden" name="pDateBeg" value="<?= $_GET['pDateBeg'] ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?= $_GET['sid'] ?>" />
<div class="col-md-2">
<button class="btn btn-default">Сформировать</button>
</div>                      

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
 <script>


    jQuery(function () {
        checkSid(function(isSidOk){
            $("#pleaseWait").show(); 
            if(isSidOk ==true){

                                    $.ajax({
            url: 'checkaccess.php'
            ,
            type: 'GET'
            ,
            data: {
                Sid: $("#Sid").val()
            }
                        ,
dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
         json = json.data;
         for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

   var  $d= json[i].RV;
   console.log($d);
   if ($d == 1)
       {    
$("#pleaseWait").show();
   $.ajax({
            url: 'sedapi.php',
                        type: 'GET'
            ,
data: {      
                Sid: $("#Sid").val(),  pStatus: $("#pStatus").val(),  pType: $("#pType").val(),  pDateBeg: $("#pDateBeg").val(),  pDateEnd: $("#pDateEnd").val()
            }
            ,
dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
        var tr;
        json = json.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DOCISN + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].ID + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].VALC2 + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DATEBEG + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DATEEND + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FULLNAME + "</td>"); 
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].REMARK + "</td>");
               $('table').first().append(tr);
        }


            }
        });

        }

        else {$('table').empty();
        $('.name').append('<span>ДОСТУП ЗАПРЕЩЕН</span>');      

        }


         }

$("#pleaseWait").hide();
            }

        });







    }else{
                                        ($(".cover").css("display", "block"));
                        ($(".modal").css("display", "block"));
                        ($(".content").css("display", "block"));
                        setTimeout('document.location.href="https://site.ru";', 3000);
            }

        })



    });




</script>
```

Comment: как называется библиотека? или это стандартный бутстрап(тогда версию пишите)?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Comment: `$('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');`